# What is this declaration exactly means as an English sentence?

Tags: c++, pointers

if i write this code: 
`Node* head;`

I understand head is a variable type of Node and it stores a variable's address type of Node.

Is that true?

Comment: `head` is a variable of type `Node*` and not `Node`. In C++ terms, `head` is a pointer to a Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets get some definitions straight.

1. Pointer - A number value of an index into memory.
2. Stack - An area of memory which is responsible for holding the values of local variables
3. Heap - An area of memory which is responsible for holding long term data.
4. Compiler - A program which translates code from a programming language into the 1's and 0's that a computer can understand

```
Node *head;
```

What this does is allocate space on the stack for a pointer. Note that only the space for the pointer is allocated, not space for the data. Now `Node` is the type. That tells the compiler what data is at that location. It also tells the compiler how to interact with the data.

```
Node *head = new Node();
```

This allocates space for the pointer on the stack. It then allocates space in the heap and returns the address (the index) to be stored in the space on the stack. Remember that data on the stack disappears after the function returns, so if you don't call `delete` to get rid of the data in the heap or pass the reference on, when the function returns you have no way to access the data or delete it; this is called a memory leak.

```
Node head;
```

This declaration, however, allocates space for all of the data for the Node object on the stack. The main difference between this and the allocation to the heap (one example above) is that this variable is LOCAL. I.e. it will disappear after the current function returns.

Answer (score 4):

```
Node* head;
```

It means create a variable by name `head` which can store the address of another variable of data type `Node`.

In simple words, `head` is a pointer of the type `Node`.
Also, you should never use uninitialized pointers like this always initialize them when you create them.

```
Node* head = NULL;
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable named head then?

Comment: Will the downvoter, care to tell what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I won't upvote either. A pointer does not necessarily "store the address of another variable". I points to a location memory, which may or may not be the location of a variable.

Comment: @larsmans: That is just being pedantic but yes you are entitled to be that.

Comment: @Als his point is important because a common beginner mistake is to do something like `Node *n;` and then `n->data`. C++ wont compile time error on the second statement because it cant tell whether or not n actually points to a variable. Furthermore, you aren't guaranteed to get a runtime error either.

Comment: @KutluhanMetin: the type of the variable is `Node*`.

Answer (score 1):

`head` is a pointer to memory with format of `Node`.

Pointer is a variable that stores a memory address.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

> The memory of your computer can be imagined as a succession of memory
>   cells, each one of the minimal size that computers manage (one byte).
>   These single-byte memory cells are numbered in a consecutive way, so
>   as, within any block of memory, every cell has the same number as the
>   previous one plus one.

Answer (score -3):

`Node *head` is what you wrote, here `*head` is a "variable" of type Node and head is a reference to it.

When you dereference head (doing *head) you obtain your variable.

Comment: -1 - `*head` is not a variable, `head` is, and it's a pointer to a `Node`.  If you dereference `head` with `*head` immediately after this un-initialized declaration, you won't obtain any variable, you will obtain a segmentation fault, since `head` isn't pointing to any `Node`, and you seem to imply that it is.